# Boot loop after ROM write  in recovery

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, downgrade, htc-sensation

I have an HTC Sensation with ICS Android on it. **How can I revert back to Gingerbread?**

I have root and s-off. I tried to flash my Gingerbread ROM (??) in the recovery but am now stuck in a boot loop.

Comment: What do you mean "no effect"? What happened when you flashed the rom?

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why do you want to revert to Gingerbread? Also, can you try another ROM? Try reflashing `/system` if that is a part of the instructions. Also try a stock factory reset.

Comment: Did you wipe before flashing?

Comment: -I tried about 12 or 15 ICS roms but gingenbread is better to me.
-Yes, I've done a full wipe before flashing

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

- Boot into Recovery
- Wipe cache
- Wipe Dalvik cache
- Wipe them again
- Install your ROM

The first successful boot afterwards is going to take a while, as it is rebuilding Dalvik cache.

If you are not boot looping here, just let it go for a long while. If it boots a while and reboots, wait some more.